# How to query with has_may/belongs_to associations in controller?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, models

I am really confused on how the has_many and belongs_to works within the controller, more specifically how to query the data.

I have a Users modal, and Tasks model, and a User can have many Tasks and Tasks belong to one particular user.

Here are my Model's:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :title, 
            presence: true, 
            length: {minimum: 5, maximum: 50}

  validates :description, 
             presence: true, 
             length: {minimum: 1, maximum: 140}
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy

   has_secure_password

   validates :email, 
             presence: true, 
             uniqueness: true    
 end
```

So in my Tasks controller for example how would I implement the this same action:

```
    def index
       # Get all tasks from database
       @tasks = Task.all
       # how would you achieve the same thing, but only show tasks that belong to a specific user? something like this:
       @tasks.users.find(:all)?
   end
```

I have been doing research but I can't seem get a grasp on this. anyways any explanation would help out a lot. thanks guys.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many

Answer (score 0):

First find the User record using find or find_by_id.

user = User.find_by_id(id)

Then call tasks on the user object,which will list all the tasks of that particular user.

list_of_tasks = user.tasks

Answer (score 0):

For proper ways of querying a has_many association, refer to Rails' documentation on eager loading associations (specifically the `includes` method):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

I'm not sure exactly what kind of information you'd like to pull from your database tables, but here are a couple examples of how you might query all tasks and their associated users.

```
@tasks_and_users = Task.all.includes(:user)

@tasks_and_users.each do |task|
  puts "The user with email '#{task.user.email}' has this task: #{task.title}"
end
```

Or, if you'd like a list of all users (regardless of whether or not they have any tasks) and their associated tasks, here is an alternative:

```
@users_and_tasks = User.all.includes(:tasks)

@users_and_tasks.each do |user|
  puts "The user with with email '#{user.email}' has the following tasks:"
  user.tasks.each do |task|
    puts "\t Task: #{task.title}"
  end
end
```

Comment: what is the convention of the actions of a particular controller when using has_many? what do they become?